# Saving XML_Query2XML output to file?

Tags: php, sql, xml, pear

I have a short script that utilizes the [XML_Query2XML](https://pear.php.net/package/XML_Query2XML/) PEAR package. It pulls data from a SQL database and outputs to the browser. The XML that appears in the browser is exactly what I want to be saved to a file, but any attempts to use `ob_get_contents` or any of the other methods I'm familiar with result in a blank output file. The code is as follows:

```
<?php


    set_include_path('/Library/WebServer/Documents/PEAR/');
    include 'XML/Query2XML.php';
    include 'MDB2.php';

    try {
        // initialize Query2XML object
        $q2x = XML_Query2XML::factory(MDB2::factory('mysql://root:pass@site.com/site'));

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM Products";
        $xml = $q2x->getFlatXML($sql);



        header('Content-Type: text/xml');
        $xml->formatOutput = true;
        echo $xml->saveXML();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


    ?>
```

I'm wondering what the general procedure is for saving files with this plugin and output type (XML). Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$xml` variable is a [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/DOMDocument) object, which means you can use its methods to save it into a file, e.g. [`save`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.save.php):

```
$xml->save('foo.xml');
```